# Buffer and its interaction with function?

Tags: c, string

I am facing some problems while understanding the following code.
It is a program to read Strings from keyboard if the length of the String is lesser than the specified size (i.e 'n' here).

If the length of a string is larger than the specified size, the remaining characters on the line will be discarded.

More specifically, I want to know what is happening inside the buffer and how `getchar()` is reading the data and not storing it in the buffer.

```
char * s_gets(char * st, int n)
{
     char * ret_val;
     int i = 0;
     ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin);

     if (ret_val) // i.e., ret_val != NULL
     {
          while (st[i] != '\n' && st[i] != '\0')
          i++;

          if (st[i] == '\n')
               st[i] = '\0';

          else // must have words[i] == '\0'
          while (getchar() != '\n')
                continue;

     }

     return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: *"how getchar() is reading the data and not storing in buffer"* - The last inner `while` loop is nothing if not self-explanatory. the value returned from `getchar()` is used only for comparison against `'\n'`, and is not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The code is slightly flawed, but does more or less the job outlined.  It uses `fgets()` to do a lot of the work.  That reads up to `n - 1` characters from standard input.  When it returns, there are a few possibilities:

1. (EOF) Nothing was available to be read.  Nothing has been put in the buffer, but `fgets()` returned `NULL`.
2. (Normal) A line has been read and fitted into the buffer `st`.  The buffer includes the newline.
3. (Overlong) Part of a line has been read, but the input did not find a newline.
4. (EOF without newline) Some data was read, but there wasn't a newline before EOF was detected.

Case 1 is simplest: the code returns NULL.  Case 2 is handled by scanning the string that's read to find the newline.  If the newline is found, it is overwritten with a null byte.  Case 3 is handled at the same time; if the value found isn't a newline, it must be the null byte.  The code drops into a loop that reads more characters until a newline is read.  Case 4 is similar to case 3 in effect, but the code in the loop mishandles this — it doesn't detect and handle EOF, so the code would fall into an indefinite loop.  That's a bug that needs to be fixed.

The `getchar()` loop doesn't assign anything to the buffer `st` — it makes no changes to `st`.  That continues to contain a null terminated string as read by `fgets()`. The `getchar()` loop reads and discards any characters left on the line that was read that did not fit into the buffer.

The code should be:

```
char *s_gets(char *st, int n)
{
    assert(n > 1 && st != NULL);
    char *ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin);

    if (ret_val != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (st[i] != '\n' && st[i] != '\0')
            i++;
        if (st[i] == '\n')
            st[i] = '\0';
        else
        {
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
        }
    }

    return ret_val;
}
```

The return value of NULL or the original string is the same as `fgets()` uses, but it isn't the most useful return value.  It would be more useful, most often, if the code returned the length of the string that it read, or returned EOF if it encountered EOF (or a read error).  The information is readily available — in the variable `i`.